# Validate form window open

Tags: jquery, forms

Guys i want when the required fields are empty, the function to open the windows dont work(when someone click in a button).

I had this code, but it doenst works:

```
$(function() {
  $('#chkveg').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

  $('#formulario-inscricao').find('input').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop('required')) {

      $('#btnget').click(function() {
        window.open($('#chkveg').val());
      })

    }
  });
```

Need some help! I have this jsfiddle, i want need include the required in fields and the window of the selects dont open if is empty: http://jsfiddle.net/sxyme9uL/4

Comment: You are binding the click event inside a loop.  That means as long as `!$(this).prop('required')` is met once, window.open is bound.

Comment: how the code will be?

Comment: i have this jsfiddle, i want need include the required in fields and the window of the selects dont open if is empty: http://jsfiddle.net/sxyme9uL/4/

Comment: I am close to being able to help you.  However, there are no `input`s in your fiddle.

Comment: the input is <input name="name" required "placeholder"=Nome" />